# A lot of apache connections: no users trying to access

Tags: apache-2.4

If I check the top command I see a lot of Apache2 workers opened (generally on idle there are at most 10 workers), and consuming a whole bunch of resources. In fact if I access the web in that server when this occur, it loads incredibly slow.

[apache connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NayVp.png)

But if I do a netstat command:

```
# netstat -ant | grep :80
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

There are no users in the system (only my connection when I try to load the site)

What can be going on? I thought it could be a cronjob, but no cronjobs either at that moment

Is it possible to "debug" this type of behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that previously there have been apache connections and processes have remained open, as is standard practice for Apache.

It varies a bit depending on what MPM (Multi Processing Module)  you use but these types of settings can be tuned by modifying the appropriate mpm configs.  For example, my server has the following -

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers             5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxRequestWorkers     150
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

MPM is responsible for handling connections, with various tradeoffs between responsiveness and resource utilization.

Comment: I see that these are the default config... it would be great to know the rationale behind the optimization of this configuration